# Probability a given markov chain is in two different states at two different times

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let us say that our state space $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

Now let us say our transition matrix $P$ is given by:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
    1/6 & 1/6 & 2/3 & 0 \\
    1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2
  \end{bmatrix}

Given that a Markov chain $X_n$ is in state 3 at time 0 (i.e $X_0 = 3$), what is the probability that it is in state 1 at time 4 and state 2 at time 5? To rephrase the question, given that $X_0 = 3$, what is the probability that $X_4 = 1$ and $X_5 = 2$ **both occur**

Originally, the way I thought to go about answering this question was to take the row matrix $\pi_0$:

\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 &1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

which gives the probability distribution of the Markov chain at time 0, and take the first entry of the row matrix given by $\pi_0P^4$, (the probability of the Markov chain being in state 1 at time 4) and the second entry of the row matrix given by $\pi_0P^5$ (the probability of the Markov chain being in state 2 at time 5, and multiplying these two entries together to get our final answer. However, this would require the two events to be independent, which, due to the definition of Markov processes, I am not sure they are. Is this approach correct? If not, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: They are not at all independent, but you can use the Markov property to compute the probability of the intersection: just multiply the probability of the earliest event, times the probability of the second event given the first, etc. These conditional probabilities can be computed from the transition matrix.

Comment: @Ian Would you be able to explain how you would apply the Markov property to this problem? Though I understand the property generally, I struggle to understand how it relates to specific computations like this one.

Comment: The derivation goes like $P(X_4=1,X_5=2 \mid X_0=3)=P(X_4=1,X_5=2 \mid X_4=1,X_0=3)P(X_4=1 \mid X_0=3)$ (which is just using the definition of conditional probability). The Markov property is used to make the simplification $P(X_4=1,X_5=2 \mid X_4=1,X_0=3)=P(X_5=2 \mid X_4=1)$ and then homogeneity tells you this is just $p_{12}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required probability is the probability of transition from state 3 to state 1 in 4 steps (between time 0 and 4), multiplied by the probability of transition from state 1 to state 2 in 1 step (between time 4 and 5). We can multiply these probabilities directly because of the Markov property: what happens before time 4 does not affect the probability of transitioning from state 1 to state 2 between times 4 and 5. In other words, the probability is equal to $$P^4_{31}\cdot P_{12}$$
Note: here $P^4_{31}$ refers to the 4-step transitional probability, not $(1/6)^4$.

Comment: Note that it is $(P^4)_{31}$ not $(P_{31})^4$; these operations absolutely do *not* commute.

Comment: @Ian here $P^4_{31}$ simply refers to the 4-step transition probability. It is not meant to be an matrix operation even though it happens to be.

Comment: It actually can be obtained by exactly that matrix operation. But that is not the point. The point is that there is a notational ambiguity, since $P_{31}$ is a thing that makes sense (in this context it's $1/6$), and so you might incorrectly think that that factor is just $(1/6)^4$. A particular author might sort out that notational ambiguity with the way they set up their notation, but we can't see the development that the OP used to get to this stage.

Comment: @Ian edited my answer to clear that up